# How to preserve repo directory after loading Jenkinsfile from that repo?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a repo with a Jenkinsfile with a script that successfully runs from a resources directory:

dir structure

```
resources/
  myscript.sh
Jenkinsfile
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('first stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh './resources/myscript.sh'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This runs on its own.

However when I try to load this Jenkinsfile from another pipeline:

```
node {
    git url: 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo'
    sh 'ls -lR' // ./resources is available
    load Jenkinsfile // ./resources is no longer available
}
```

It will start to run the stage but loses the resources directory:

```
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/mypipeline@tmp/durable-d40c5f4e/script.sh:
line 6: ./resources/myscript.sh: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can keep/get access to the resources directory? Workspace appears to change from `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mypipeline/workspace` to `/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/mypipeline` and I lose access to the old one with the resources.

I am trying to create a single pipeline that can point to multiple repos and run their respective resources.

Comment: I believe the `load Jenkinsfile` executes another pipeline scope which has a workspace distinct from the original containing your SCM checkout. I think you want a shared library instead.

Comment: Yeah I think that is what it is doing with the workspace. Shared library for the Jenkinsfile, or the resources, or both? It feels a bit strange because for each of my repos, the Jenkinsfiles and the resources will be different, so there is not much shared functionality between them.

Comment: If the `Jenkinsfile` will be different to such a degree that you cannot share functionality, then you really should consider different pipelines.